# FFMPEG compile on OS X 10.9 Mavericks with deployment target 10.6

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, osx-mavericks

I am trying to build ffmepg on OS X 10.9 and everything works correctly, but it seems that the deployment target is ignored. Here is how I am configuring the ffmpeg:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L${TARGET}/lib $CFLAGS"
export CFLAGS="-I${TARGET}/include $LDFLAGS -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.6"
./configure --prefix=${TARGET}/compile --cc=clang --as=yasm --extra-version=inpos --disable-shared --enable-static --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-postproc --enable-gray --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libxvid --enable-libspeex --enable-bzlib --enable-zlib  --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb
```

Is there any problem that causes the `mmacosx-version-min=10.6` to be ignored?